# Как сложить все размеры дочерних объектов и задать размер родителя как их сумму UI Unity

Tags: unity3d, ui, unity3d-android

Нужно изменить размер Message как сумму размеров дочерних объектов (Author, Avatar, GameObject).
Пытался через ContentSizeFitter, но он все ломает.

[![Компоненты объекта-родителя][1]][1]
[image: Компоненты Author]
[image: Компоненты Avatar]
[image: Компоненты GameObject (текста)]
[image: Какой должен быть размер объекта-родителя]

@Lexanom
Сделал вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Content Size Fitter не работает без компонента Layout. Я бы положил username и геймобжект с текстом в еще один объект-контейнер с Vertical Layout и Size Fitter с заполнением по высоте. А на Message соответственно Horizontal Layout и Size Fitter по высоте и горизонтали.

Comment: @Lexanom сделал, как вы сказали, проверьте скрины